allure-results not creating with main method of TestNG code
When I am running my tests from with testng.xml it works but when I run with main method (code added below) these allure-results are NOT created while the TestNG test-output folder is created successfully
I have set the allure.properties as allure.results.directory=allure-results and placed it at the location "src/test/resources"
I need this to run from this main method as I have to run these tests from package jar file, so in command I am adding this runner class which executes the testng.xml and triggers testcases
Version of allures I am using:
      <properties>
          <allure.version>2.27.0</allure.version>
          <aspectj.version>1.9.22.1</aspectj.version>
      </properties>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    

Run the test with this Runner class
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add("testng.xml");
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        testng.run();
    }
}

